# open UL with breadcrumb

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, breadcrumbs

With this JS im creating a breadcrumb above my menu.
it also animates the menu  which is hidden.

--> http://jsfiddle.net/4XTPR/9/

--> newer Version: http://jsfiddle.net/4XTPR/26/

```
$('#menu a').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');

      $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
          var $a = $(li).children('a').clone().prepend(' > ');
          $bc.prepend($a);

          /*animate Menu*/
          $(li).children('.sub-menu').animate({
              opacity: 1,
              left: "10"
              }, 200, function() {
                  // Animation complete.
              });
           /*End animate Menu*/
          }); 

    $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<a href="#home">Home</a>') );
    return false;
})
```

How can i make the breadcrumb interact with my menu? i would like to open (animate back) the related menu layer on mouse over (and restore it on mouse out) but i just cannot find a solution.

**EDIT:**

Added class and data:

```
<a href="#" data-depth="1">ParentXY</a>
<ul class="sub-menu 1" >...
```

Current solution:

```
    var activedepth = "0";

    $('#menu a').on('click', function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');
        var activedepth =  $(this).data('depth');


          $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
              var $a = $(li).children('a').clone().prepend(' > ');
              $bc.prepend($a);

              /*animate Menu*/
              $(li).children('.sub-menu').animate({
                  opacity: 1,
                  left: "10"
                  }, 200, function() {
                      // Animation complete.
                  });
               /*End animate Menu*/
              }); 



        $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<a href="#" data-depth="0">Home</a>') );


/*Mouseover Actions*/

        $('.item a').on('mouseenter', function() {
            var depthwert = $(this).data('depth');
            for (var i = activedepth; i > depthwert; i--){
                    $('#nav .'+i).stop().animate({left:"295"},200);
                }
            });

        $('.item a').on('mouseout', function() { 
            var depthwert = $(this).data('depth');
            for (var f = 0; f <= activedepth; f++){
                    $('#nav .'+f).stop().animate({left:"10"},200);
                }
            });                    


        return false;
    });
```

Comment: just listen for a click in the breadcrumb as you do for the "#menu a" and perform the back-animation there

Comment: yes, but when i open 3 it to layer 3 and go with my mouse to home it should animate all layers back. so i will have to add the function when im creating the breadcrumb (right?) and animate back ALL sub-menu classes under the related sub-menu. how to do that?

Comment: I made a part of what i want but its working perfectly... http://jsfiddle.net/4XTPR/24/

Comment: maybe you should just do it a little different. try to add a class to every breadcrumb-point you are adding. For example, if you click Parent 1 you add the class "parent". and if you are in a child object and click on parent 1, you know that you have to go one back. Maybe I'll have time later on to work on a fiddle for that.

Comment: Hi, thank you. i worked out a solution with data and it works for mouse over right now. its not perfect so if someone knows a better solution i would be really happy. now i have to add the click funktions. --> http://jsfiddle.net/4XTPR/38/